# How can i make my Javascript function instantly send me to a subpage?

Tags: javascript

Im very new to Javascript, so apologies if this is very basic.
The only way i know how to send people to subpages is by having them click a link. Is there any way to make a javascript function that sends people to a subpage?

Since im very new to javascript, i havent been able to try much. The only way i can make subpages is having the user click a link. I need to send them to a subpage with a function

Comment: What's "a subpage"?  Can you provide an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @David probably just a redirect or something similar

Comment: Do you mind sharing the function in question?